# ERROR: The Compose file './addOrg3/docker/docker-compose-couch-org3.yaml' is invalid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I have downloaded the Hyperledger Fabric Docker images and samples. Something goes wrong when I deploy a test network by using scripts that are provided in the fabric-samples repository.
[Using the Fabric test network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html)

When I execute `./network.sh down` I got the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './addOrg3/docker/docker-compose-couch-org3.yaml' is invalid because:
networks.test value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)
```

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml" is unsupported. 
You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version.
Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions 
under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions 
at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

Comment: Edit the question and add your `.yaml` contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Today I have faced this issue it's because of the older docker-compose version please remove and install the latest docker-compose version then it works.
My current docker-compose version
`docker-compose version`
`docker-compose version 1.28.5, build c4eb3a1f`
`docker-py version: 4.4.4`
`CPython version: 3.7.10`
`OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019`

Previously it was docker-compose version 1.26 something

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just solved this ERROR by following your comment.```docker-compose version 1.29.0, build 07737305```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your docker-compose version to the latest by following commands

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

then give permissions using below

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

then check version

```
docker-compose --version
```

it worked for me